How to update, remove and append objects in a nested arrays using zod
I am using the schema below and my biggest problem begins when I try to do some operations in the details array inside the budgets array.
export const financePlannerFormSchema = z.object({
  month: z.string().nonempty("Escolha o mês de referência").min(4, "Mês não pode ser menor que 4 caracteres").max(10, "Mês não pode exceder 10 caracteres").refine(m => ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"].includes(m), "Mês inválido"),
  income: z.coerce.number().nonnegative("Renda não pode ser negativa").min(1, "Renda mensal não pode ser menor que R$ 1"),
  budgets: z.array(z.object({
    name: z.string().nonempty("Escreva o nome da diretriz").min(2, "Nome da diretriz deve ter pelo menos 2 caracteres").max(30, "Nome da diretriz não pode exceder 30 caracteres"), 
    percent: z.coerce.number().nonnegative("Porcentagem não pode ser negativa").gt(0, "Porcentagem deve ser maior que 0%."),
    details: z.array(z.object({
      description: z.string().nonempty("Descreva o destino do recurso").min(2, "Destino do recurso deve ter pelo menos 2 caracteres").max(30, "Detalhe não pode exceder 30 caracteres"), 
      value: z.coerce.number().nonnegative("Valor não pode ser negativo")
    })).min(1, 'Forneça pelo menos um detalhe orçamentário')
  })).min(1, "Forneça pelo menos uma diretriz"),
})

By using the useFieldArray method I have easy access to the budgets array, but not to the details array.
  const {fields, append, remove, update} = useFieldArray({
    control: control,
    name: 'budgets'
  })

  const handleAppendMainArray = () => {
    append({
      name: 'test',
      percent: 10,
      details: []
    })
  }

So, my question is: how to do the basic operations like append, remove and update only in the details array?
I would like to trigger a function like handleAppendDetailsArray and do the operations in a button's click.


You can use useFieldArray nested also

import { Fragment } from "react";
import { useFieldArray, useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      budgets: [
        {
          name: "test",
          percent: 10,
          details: [{ description: "des", value: 1 }],
        },
      ],
    },
  });
  const { fields, append, remove, update } = useFieldArray({
    control: form.control,
    name: "budgets",
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <ul>
        {form.watch("budgets").map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <span>
              {item.name + " | " + item.percent + " | "}
              {item.details.map((d, ind) => (
                <Fragment key={ind}>{d.description}</Fragment>
              ))}
            </span>

            <button className="ml-5" type="button">
              Update
            </button>
            <Edit index={index} control={form.control} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          append({
            name: "test",
            percent: 10,
            details: [{ description: "des", value: 1 }],
          })
        }
      >
        append
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const Edit = ({ index, control }) => {
  const { fields, append, remove, update } = useFieldArray({
    control: control,
    name: `budgets.${index}.details`,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          append({
            description: "des",
            value: 1,
          });
        }}
        className="text-blue-500"
      >
        append
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          remove(index);
        }}
        className="text-red-500"
      >
        delete
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

You can learn more here
